# JAVA - ERROR EN EL MENSAJE

Tags: java

Tengo estas dos clases.
Brevemente, al estante tengo que agregarle un frasco...peso, cantidad son variables que aun no defino.. para el caso no importan.
El tema es que encuentro el estante pero no me agrega el frasco.
Creo que me equivoco en el mensaje para agregar y no me doy cuenta.
¿Alguien se da cuenta del error?.

Cualquier aclaración, denme aviso...

```
public class Almacen {
private ArrayList<Frasco>frascos;
private ArrayList<Estante>estantes;

public Almacen() {
    frascos = new ArrayList<Frasco>();
    estantes = new ArrayList<Estante>();
}

public void agregaFrasco() {
    Scanner entra = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INGRESE EL CODIGO DEL FRASCO");
    int cdf = entra.nextInt();
    Frasco fra = this.buscaFrasco(cdf);
    if ( fra != null)
        System.out.println("EL FRASCO EXISTE");
    else {
        System.out.println("INGRESE EL PESO");
        float pe = entra.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("INGRESE LA DENSIDAD DEL PRODUCTO");
        Float de = entra.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("INGRESE LA MARCA");
        String ma = entra.next();
        Frasco fras = new Frasco(cdf, pe, de, ma);
        frascos.add(fras);
        System.out.println("EL FRASCO SE AGREGO CORRECTAMENTE");
    }
}


public void agregaEstante() {
    Scanner entra = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INGRESE EL NUMERO DEL ESTANTE");
    int nd = entra.nextInt();
    Estante esta = this.buscaEstante(nd);
    if(esta != null)
        System.out.println("ESTANTE YA CARGADO");
    else {
        System.out.println("INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE FRASCOS QUE SOPORTA EL ESTANTE");
        int cd = entra.nextInt();
        System.out.println("INGRESE EL PESO MAXIMO");
        float d = entra.nextFloat();
        Estante es = new Estante(nd, cd, d);
        estantes.add(es);
        System.out.println("SE AGREGO UN ESTANTE NUEVO");
    }
}

public void agregaFrascosAlEstante() {
    Scanner entra = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INGRESE EL NUMERO DE ESTANTE");
    int ne = entra.nextInt();
    int b = 0;
    while(b < estantes.size() && !(estantes.get(b).sosElEstante(ne)))
        b++;
    //Estante estan = this.buscaEstante(ne);
    //if(estan != null) {
    System.out.println(estantes.get(b).darCantidadDeFrascos());
    System.out.println(estantes.get(b).darNumeroDeEstante());
    System.out.println(estantes.get(b).darPesoMaximo());

        if(b < estantes.size()) {
            System.out.println("QUIERE AGREGAR UN FRASCO AL ESTANTE?");
            System.out.println("INGRESE 1 O 0 PARA SALIR");
            int op = entra.nextInt();
        do {
            System.out.println("INGRESE EL CODIGO DEL FRASCO");
            int cd = entra.nextInt();
            Frasco fra = this.buscaFrasco(cd);
            if(fra != null) {
                Estante estan = estantes.get(b);       //<<<
                estan.agregaFrasco(fra);               //<<< problem!
                //estantes.get(b).agregaFrasco(fra);   //<<<
                //estan.agregaFrasco(fra);             //<<<
                System.out.println("SE AGREGO UN FRASCO AL ESTANTE ok");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("EL FRASCO NO EXISTE");
        }while(op != 0);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("ESE ESTANTE NO EXISTE");
}

public class Estante {
private int numeroDeEstante;
private int cantidadDeFrascos;
private float pesoMaximo;
private ArrayList <Frasco>frascos;

public Estante(int nde, int cdf, float pm) {
    numeroDeEstante = nde;
    cantidadDeFrascos = cdf;
    pesoMaximo = pm;
}

public void agregaFrasco(Frasco fr) {
    frascos.add(fr);
}
```

---

El codigo completo es:
creo que estoy manejando mal la forma que agrego un frasco a un estante...

```
import java.util.*;
public class Empresa {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Almacen esta = new Almacen();
    Scanner entra = new Scanner(System.in);
    entra.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    int opc = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("1- AGREGA FRASCO");
        System.out.println("6- agrega un estante");
        System.out.println("7- AGREGA UN FRASCO A UN ESTANTE");
        opc = entra.nextInt();
        switch(opc) {
        case 1:{
            esta.agregaFrasco();
            break;
        }
        case 6:{
            esta.agregaEstante();;
            break;
        }
        case 7:{
            esta.agregaFrascosAlEstante();;
            break;
        }
        }
    }while(opc != 0);

   }
  }

import java.util.*;
public class Almacen {
 private ArrayList<Frasco>frascos;
 private ArrayList<Estante>estantes;

public Almacen() {
    frascos = new ArrayList<Frasco>();
    estantes = new ArrayList<Estante>();
 }

public void agregaFrasco() {
    Scanner entra = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INGRESE EL CODIGO DEL FRASCO");
    int cdf = entra.nextInt();
    Frasco fra = this.buscaFrasco(cdf);
    if ( fra != null)
        System.out.println("EL FRASCO EXISTE");
    else {
        System.out.println("INGRESE EL PESO");
        float pe = entra.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("INGRESE LA DENSIDAD DEL PRODUCTO");
        Float de = entra.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("INGRESE LA MARCA");
        String ma = entra.next();
        Frasco fras = new Frasco(cdf, pe, de, ma);
        frascos.add(fras);
        System.out.println("EL FRASCO SE AGREGO CORRECTAMENTE");
    }
}

public void agregaEstante() {
    Scanner entra = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INGRESE EL NUMERO DEL ESTANTE");
    int nd = entra.nextInt();
    Estante esta = this.buscaEstante(nd);
    if(esta != null)
        System.out.println("ESTANTE YA CARGADO");
    else {
        System.out.println("INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE FRASCOS QUE SOPORTA EL ESTANTE");
        int cd = entra.nextInt();
        System.out.println("INGRESE EL PESO MAXIMO");
        float d = entra.nextFloat();
        Estante es = new Estante(nd, cd, d);
        estantes.add(es);
        System.out.println("SE AGREGO UN ESTANTE NUEVO");
    }
}

public void agregaFrascosAlEstante() {
    Scanner entra = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INGRESE EL NUMERO DE ESTANTE");
    int ne = entra.nextInt();
    int b = 0;
    while(b < estantes.size() && !(estantes.get(b).sosElEstante(ne)))
        b++;
    //Estante estan = this.buscaEstante(ne);
    //if(estan != null) {
    System.out.println(estantes.get(b).darCantidadDeFrascos());
    System.out.println(estantes.get(b).darNumeroDeEstante());
    System.out.println(estantes.get(b).darPesoMaximo());

        if(b < estantes.size()) {
            System.out.println("QUIERE AGREGAR UN FRASCO AL ESTANTE?");
            System.out.println("INGRESE 1 O 0 PARA SALIR");
            int op = entra.nextInt();
        do {
            System.out.println("INGRESE EL CODIGO DEL FRASCO");
            int cd = entra.nextInt();
            Frasco fra = this.buscaFrasco(cd);
            if(fra != null) {
                Estante estan = estantes.get(b);
                //estan.agregandoFrasco(fra);       <<
                //estantes.get(b).agregaFrasco(fra);    << esta comentado, ac'a esta el error
                //estan.agregaFrasco(fra);      <<
                System.out.println("SE AGREGO UN FRASCO AL ESTANTE CON EXITO");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("EL FRASCO NO EXISTE");
        }while(op != 0);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("ESE ESTANTE NO EXISTE");
}

import java.util.*;
public class Estante {

    private int numeroDeEstante;
    private int cantidadDeFrascos;
    private float pesoMaximo;
    private ArrayList <Frasco>frascos;

public Estante(int nde, int cdf, float pm) {
    numeroDeEstante = nde;
    cantidadDeFrascos = cdf;
    pesoMaximo = pm;
}

public void agregandoFrasco(Frasco fr) {
    frascos.add(fr);
}

public int darNumeroDeEstante() {
    return numeroDeEstante;
}

public boolean sosElEstante(int cde) {
    return ( numeroDeEstante == cde);
}

public void setCantidadDeFrascos(int v) {
    cantidadDeFrascos = v;
}

public void setPesoMaximo(float s) {
    pesoMaximo = s;
}

public int darCantidadDeFrascos() {
    return cantidadDeFrascos;
}

public float darPesoMaximo() {
    return pesoMaximo;
  }
}


public class Frasco {
    private int codigoDelFrasco;
    private float peso;
    private float densidad;
    private String marcaDelProducto;

public Frasco(int cdf, float pe, float den, String mdp) {
    codigoDelFrasco = cdf;
    peso = pe;
    densidad = den;
    marcaDelProducto = mdp;
}

public boolean sosElFrasco(int ff) {
    return ( codigoDelFrasco == ff);
}

public int darCodigo() {
    return codigoDelFrasco;
}

public float darPeso() {
    return peso;
}

public float darDensidad() {
    return densidad;
}

public String darMarcaDelProducto() {
    return marcaDelProducto;
 }
}
```

Comment: Dónde está tu clase Frasco? y el main?, podrías agregar todas las clases involucradas? (código de todo). Es complicado detectar el error cuando faltan cosas para poder reproducir tu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He tenido mucha dificultad para entender tu ejercicio debido a la falta de convención en los nombres, variables, métodos, etc... Siempre hay que tratar de utilizar nombres genéricos y hacer uso de la convención que tenga un lenguaje para cuando otros programadores analicen tu código puedan entenderlo a la primera.

He modificado tu código para tratar de **cumplir con las convenciones en Java**. Evita el uso de variables llamadas: opc, cdf, fra, etc.. Ninguna otra persona podrá entender su significado excepto tu. Cuando estés trabajando con un grupo de programadores en algún proyecto, el uso de la convención es muy importante.

He usado `Getters` y `Setters` en tus clases al igual que `For-each loop` para determinar si un frasco/estante existe o no.

La [documentación de Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) indica en resumen su convención de nombres.

Ahora mismo he hecho tu ejercicio completamente, dígase Agregar un frasco, Agregar un estante, Agregar un frasco a un estante, Validar si un frasco/estante existe o no. Como hice modificaciones en cada una de tus clases, tendré que pegarte todo el código, cada clase por separado.

He tratado de comentar todos los cambios para que puedas entender qué he hecho.

**Clase Empresa:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Empresa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Almacen almacen = new Almacen();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        int opcion = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("1- AGREGA FRASCO");
            System.out.println("6- agrega un estante");
            System.out.println("7- AGREGA UN FRASCO A UN ESTANTE");
            opcion = scanner.nextInt();
            switch (opcion) {
            case 1: {
                almacen.agregaFrasco();
                break;
            }
            case 6: {
                almacen.agregaEstante();
                break;
            }
            case 7: {
                almacen.agregaFrascosAlEstante();
                break;
            }
            }
        } while (opcion != 0);

        // Cerrar Scanner
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

**Clase Almacen:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Almacen {

    private ArrayList<Frasco> frascos;
    private ArrayList<Estante> estantes;

    public Almacen() {
        frascos = new ArrayList<Frasco>();
        estantes = new ArrayList<Estante>();
    }

    public void agregaFrasco() {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("INGRESE EL CODIGO DEL FRASCO");
        int codigoFrasco = scanner.nextInt();

        // Variable boolean para determinar si existe o no el frasco
        boolean existeElFrasco = false;

        // Ver si existe un frasco con ese código
        // For-each loop
        for (Frasco frasco : frascos) {
            if (frasco.getCodigoDelFrasco() == codigoFrasco) {

                // Frasco encontrado
                existeElFrasco = true;
            }
        }

        if (existeElFrasco) { // Si existe

            System.out.println("EL FRASCO EXISTE");

        } else { // Si no existe

            System.out.println("INGRESE EL PESO");
            float peso = scanner.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("INGRESE LA DENSIDAD DEL PRODUCTO");
            Float densidad = scanner.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("INGRESE LA MARCA");
            String marcaDelProducto = scanner.next();
            Frasco frasco = new Frasco(codigoFrasco, peso, densidad, marcaDelProducto);
            frascos.add(frasco);
            System.out.println("EL FRASCO SE AGREGO CORRECTAMENTE");

        }
    }

    public void agregaEstante() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("INGRESE EL NUMERO DEL ESTANTE");
        int numeroDeEstante = scanner.nextInt();

        // Variable boolean para determinar si existe o no el estante
        boolean existeElEstante = false;

        // Ver si existe un estante con ese número
        // For-each loop
        for (Estante estante : estantes) {
            if (estante.getNumeroDeEstante() == numeroDeEstante) {

                // Estante encontrado
                existeElEstante = true;
            }
        }

        if (existeElEstante) // Si existe

            System.out.println("ESTANTE YA CARGADO");

        else { // Si no existe

            System.out.println("INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE FRASCOS QUE SOPORTA EL ESTANTE");
            int cantidadDeFrascos = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("INGRESE EL PESO MAXIMO");
            float pesoMaximo = scanner.nextFloat();
            Estante estante = new Estante(numeroDeEstante, cantidadDeFrascos, pesoMaximo);
            estantes.add(estante);
            System.out.println("SE AGREGO UN ESTANTE NUEVO");

        }
    }

    public void agregaFrascosAlEstante() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("INGRESE EL NUMERO DE ESTANTE");
        int numeroDeEstante = scanner.nextInt();

        // Variable boolean para determinar si existe o no el estante
        boolean existeElEstante = false;

        // Posición del estante en el ArrayList
        int posicionEstante = 0;

        // Ver si existe un estante con ese número
        for (int i = 0; i < estantes.size(); i++) {
            if (estantes.get(i).getNumeroDeEstante() == numeroDeEstante) {

                // Estante encontrado
                existeElEstante = true;

                // Guardar posicion
                posicionEstante = i;

            }
        }

        if (existeElEstante) {
            System.out.println("ESTANTE ENCONTRADO");
            System.out.println("Numero de estante: " + estantes.get(posicionEstante).getNumeroDeEstante());
            System.out.println("Cantidad de frascos: " + estantes.get(posicionEstante).getCantidadDeFrascos());
            System.out.println("Peso maximo: " + estantes.get(posicionEstante).getPesoMaximo());


            System.out.println("QUIERE AGREGAR UN FRASCO AL ESTANTE?");
            System.out.println("INGRESE 1 O 0 PARA SALIR");
            int opcion = scanner.nextInt();

            do {
                System.out.println("INGRESE EL CODIGO DEL FRASCO");
                int codigoFrasco = scanner.nextInt();

                // Variable boolean para determinar si existe o no el frasco
                boolean existeElFrasco = false;

                // Posición del frasco en el ArrayList
                int posicionFrasco = 0;

                // Ver si existe un frasco con ese código
                // For-each loop
                for (int i = 0; i < estantes.size(); i++) {
                    if (frascos.get(i).getCodigoDelFrasco() == codigoFrasco) {

                        // Estante encontrado
                        existeElFrasco = true;

                        // Guardar posicion
                        posicionFrasco = i;

                    }
                }

                if (existeElFrasco) { // Si existe

                    // Obtener el frasco deseado en forma de instancia
                    Frasco instanciaFrasco = frascos.get(posicionFrasco);

                    // Agregar al ArrayList de frascos que tiene el estante
                    estantes.get(posicionEstante).addFrasco(instanciaFrasco);

                    System.out.println("SE AGREGO UN FRASCO AL ESTANTE CON EXITO");

                } else {// Si no existe

                    System.out.println("EL FRASCO NO EXISTE");

                }

                // Salir del do-while
                opcion = 0;

            } while (opcion != 0);

        } else {
            System.out.println("ESTANTE NO ENCONTRADO");
        }
    }
}
```

**Clase Estante:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Estante {

    private int numeroDeEstante;
    private int cantidadDeFrascos;
    private float pesoMaximo;

    // Crear ArrayList a la primera
    private ArrayList<Frasco> frascos = new ArrayList<Frasco>();

    // Constructor
    public Estante(int numeroDeEstante, int cantidadDeFrascos, float pesoMaximo) {
        super();
        this.numeroDeEstante = numeroDeEstante;
        this.cantidadDeFrascos = cantidadDeFrascos;
        this.pesoMaximo = pesoMaximo;
    }

    // Getters & Setters
    public int getNumeroDeEstante() {
        return numeroDeEstante;
    }

    public void setNumeroDeEstante(int numeroDeEstante) {
        this.numeroDeEstante = numeroDeEstante;
    }

    public int getCantidadDeFrascos() {
        return cantidadDeFrascos;
    }

    public void setCantidadDeFrascos(int cantidadDeFrascos) {
        this.cantidadDeFrascos = cantidadDeFrascos;
    }

    public float getPesoMaximo() {
        return pesoMaximo;
    }

    public void setPesoMaximo(float pesoMaximo) {
        this.pesoMaximo = pesoMaximo;
    }

    public ArrayList<Frasco> getFrascos() {
        return frascos;
    }

    // Agregar un frasco al ArrayList
    public void addFrasco(Frasco frasco) {
        this.frascos.add(frasco);
    }

}
```

**Clase Frasco:**

```
public class Frasco {

    private int codigoDelFrasco;
    private float peso;
    private float densidad;
    private String marcaDelProducto;

    // Constructor
    public Frasco(int codigoDelFrasco, float peso, float densidad, String marcaDelProducto) {
        super();
        this.codigoDelFrasco = codigoDelFrasco;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.densidad = densidad;
        this.marcaDelProducto = marcaDelProducto;
    }

    // Getters & Setters
    public int getCodigoDelFrasco() {
        return codigoDelFrasco;
    }

    public void setCodigoDelFrasco(int codigoDelFrasco) {
        this.codigoDelFrasco = codigoDelFrasco;
    }

    public float getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }

    public void setPeso(float peso) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    public float getDensidad() {
        return densidad;
    }

    public void setDensidad(float densidad) {
        this.densidad = densidad;
    }

    public String getMarcaDelProducto() {
        return marcaDelProducto;
    }

    public void setMarcaDelProducto(String marcaDelProducto) {
        this.marcaDelProducto = marcaDelProducto;
    }

}
```

Espero haberte ayudado amigo!. Espero que puedas completar lo que te haga falta.