# FALLA LLAMADA A METODO

Tags: java, método

Lo simplifique para entenderlo y que sea un poco m'as claro.
El tema es que con la alternativa que recib'i sigue fallando al momento de llamar el metodo para agregar un frasco a un estante..
Probe y tengo la instancia correcta del frasco y la del estante.
gracias.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ejecutora {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Compania compa = new Compania();
    Scanner entra = new Scanner(System.in);
    entra.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    int opc = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("1- AGREGA FRASCO");
        System.out.println("2- agrega estante");
        System.out.println("3- AGREGA UN FRASCO A UN ESTANTE");
        System.out.println("4- muestra todo lo que hay en los estantes");
        opc = entra.nextInt();
        switch(opc) {
        case 1:{
            compa.addFrasco();
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            compa.addEstante();
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            compa.addFrascoEnEstante();
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            compa.listFrascos();
            break;
        }
        }
    }while(opc != 0);
    }}


 import java.util.*;
 public class Compania {
 private ArrayList<Estante>estantes;
 private ArrayList<Frasco>frascos;

public Compania() {
    estantes = new ArrayList<Estante>();
    frascos = new ArrayList<Frasco>();
}

public void listFrascos() {
    for (Estante estante: estantes) {
        System.out.println(estante.getNumeroDeEstante());
        for (Frasco frasco: frascos) {
            System.out.println(frasco.getCodigoDelFrasco());
        }
    }
}

public void addFrascoEnEstante() {
    Scanner entra = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INGRESE EL CODIGO DEL ESTANTE");
    int codEstante = entra.nextInt();
    boolean estaElEstante = false;
    int posicionDelEstante = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < estantes.size() ; i++) {
        if ( estantes.get(i).getNumeroDeEstante() == codEstante) {
            estaElEstante = true;
            posicionDelEstante = i;
        }
    }
    if ( estaElEstante) {
        System.out.println("INGR -1- SIGUE -0- PARA SALIR");
        int rta = entra.nextInt();
        do {
            System.out.println("INGRESE EL CODIGO DEL FRASCO");
            int codFrasco = entra.nextInt();
            boolean frascoEsta = false;
            int lugarDelFrasco = 0;
            for ( int a = 0; a < frascos.size(); a++) {
                if ( frascos.get(a).getCodigoDelFrasco() == codFrasco) {
                    frascoEsta = true;
                    lugarDelFrasco = a;
                }
            }
            if ( frascoEsta) {
                Frasco instanciaDelFrasco = frascos.get(lugarDelFrasco);
                estantes.get(posicionDelEstante).addFrasco(instanciaDelFrasco);
                System.out.println("SE AGREGO UN FRASCO A UN ESTANTE");
            }
        }while ( rta != 0 );
    }
}

public void addFrasco() {
    Scanner entra = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INGRESE EL CODIGO DEL FRASCO");
    int codFrasco = entra.nextInt();
    Frasco frasco = this.searchFrasco(codFrasco);
    if ( frasco != null) {
        System.out.println("EL FRASCO YA EXISTE");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("INGRESE EL PESO");
        float elpeso = entra.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("INGRESE LA DENSIDAD DEL PRODUCTO");
        Float ladensi = entra.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("INGRESE LA MARCA");
        String lamarca = entra.next();
        Frasco elfrasco = new Frasco (codFrasco, elpeso, ladensi, lamarca);
        frascos.add(elfrasco);
        System.out.println("SE AGREGO UN FRASCO CON EXITO");
    }
}

public void addEstante() {
    Scanner entra = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INGRESE EL NUMERO DEL ESTANTE");
    int numEstante = entra.nextInt();
    Estante estante = this.searchEstante(numEstante);
    if ( estante != null) {
        System.out.println("EL ESTANTE YA EXISTE");
    }
    else {
            System.out.println("INGRESE  CANTIDAD DE FRASCOS DEL ESTANTE");
            int cantFrascos = entra.nextInt();
            System.out.println("PESO MAXIMO QUE CARGA EL ESTANTE");
            float pesoMax = entra.nextFloat();
            Estante estant = new Estante( numEstante, cantFrascos, pesoMax);
            estantes.add(estant);
            System.out.println("EL ESTANTE SE AGREGO CON EXITO");
        }
    }

public Frasco searchFrasco (int val) {
    int a = 0;
    while ( a < frascos.size() && !( frascos.get(a).sosCodigoDelFrasco(val)))
        a++;
    if ( a < frascos.size()) {
        return frascos.get(a);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

public Estante searchEstante (int val) {
    int e = 0;
    while ( e < estantes.size() && !( estantes.get(e).sosNumEstante(val)))
        e++;
    if ( e < estantes.size()) {
        return estantes.get(e);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }}}


import java.util.*;
public class Estante {
private int numeroDeEstante;
private int cantidadDeFrascos;
private float pesoMaximo;
private ArrayList <Frasco> frascos;

public Estante ( int numDeEstante, int cantDeFras, float pesoMax) {
    numeroDeEstante = numDeEstante;
    cantidadDeFrascos = cantDeFras;
    pesoMaximo = pesoMax;
}

public int getNumeroDeEstante() {
    return numeroDeEstante;
}

public void setNumeroDeEstante(int numeroDeEstante) {
    this.numeroDeEstante = numeroDeEstante;
}

public int getCantidadDeFrascos() {
    return cantidadDeFrascos;
}

public void setCantidadDeFrascos(int cantidadDeFrascos) {
    this.cantidadDeFrascos = cantidadDeFrascos;
}

public float getPesoMaximo() {
    return pesoMaximo;
}

public void setPesoMaximo(float pesoMaximo) {
    this.pesoMaximo = pesoMaximo;
}

public ArrayList<Frasco> getFrascos() {
    return frascos;
}

public void setFrascos(ArrayList<Frasco> frascos) {
    this.frascos = frascos;
}

public boolean sosNumEstante(int valor) {
    return numeroDeEstante == valor;
}

public void addFrasco(Frasco frasco) {
    frascos.add(frasco);
}}


public class Frasco {
private int codigoDelFrasco;
private float peso;
private float densidad;
private String marcaDelProducto;

public Frasco (int codDelFrasco, float pes, float densid, String marcaDelProd) {
    codigoDelFrasco = codDelFrasco;
    peso = pes;
    densidad = densid;
    marcaDelProducto = marcaDelProd;
}

public int getCodigoDelFrasco() {
    return codigoDelFrasco;
}

public void setCodigoDelFrasco(int codigoDelFrasco) {
    this.codigoDelFrasco = codigoDelFrasco;
}

public float getPeso() {
    return peso;
}

public void setPeso(float peso) {
    this.peso = peso;
}

public float getDensidad() {
    return densidad;
}

public void setDensidad(float densidad) {
    this.densidad = densidad;
}

public String getMarcaDelProducto() {
    return marcaDelProducto;
}

public void setMarcaDelProducto(String marcaDelProducto) {
    this.marcaDelProducto = marcaDelProducto;
}

public boolean sosCodigoDelFrasco(int valor) {
    return codigoDelFrasco == valor;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tenías por qué crear una pregunta nueva si ya tienes una abierta sobre tu mismo ejercicio aquí: [JAVA - ERROR EN EL MENSAJE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168133/java-error-en-el-mensaje/). Veo que mi respuesta te ayudó ya que utilizas algo del código que te propuse, me alegro pero, no has agradecido eligiendo mi respuesta como seleccionada y tampoco has votado por ella.

1. En el `switch` no tienes por qué tener `{ }` después de los `case`. No son necesarios, puedes revisar la documentación oficial aquí: [The switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).
2. En tu clase `Compania` no muestras un mensaje de aviso cuando no se encuentra un frasco/estante con el código proporcionado. En adición, no tienes una forma de salir del `do-while`. Cuando se agrega un frasco a un estante debes inicializar `rta = 0`.

Código arreglado, dentro del método `addFrascoEnEstante`:

```
.
...
....
if (estaElEstante) {
            ..
            ...
            ....
                if (frascoEsta) {
                    Frasco instanciaDelFrasco = frascos.get(lugarDelFrasco);
                    estantes.get(posicionDelEstante).addFrasco(instanciaDelFrasco);
                    System.out.println("SE AGREGO UN FRASCO A UN ESTANTE");
                    rta = 0; // Para salir del do-while
                } else { // Avisar al usuario si el frasco no ha sido encontrado
                    System.out.println("FRASCO NO ENCONTRADO");
                }
            } while (rta != 0);
        } else { // Avisar al usuario si el estante no ha sido encontrado
            System.out.println("ESTANTE NO ENCONTRADO");
        }
...
..
.
```

3. El problema que tienes se trata de un `NullPointerException` debido a que dentro de la clase `Estante`, el `ArrayList<Frasco> frascos` no está creado. Tienes la variable declarada pero, nunca haces `new ArrayList<Frasco>()`.

Código arreglado, dentro de la clase `Estante`:

```
public class Estante {
    .
    ..
    private ArrayList<Frasco> frascos = new ArrayList<Frasco>();
    ..
    .
}
```

Puedes tratar de hacer esto en el constructor de la clase o en el lugar que te apetezca.

He probado el ejercicio nuevamente con estos cambios y funciona correctamente.

Espero haberte ayudado. Si alguna Respuesta te ha ayudado, no olvides seleccionarla como Respuesta Elegida y votar por ella. Saludos.